# Numerical solutions of a fourth order PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Let $B_R$ be a ball of radius $R>0$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider the PDE $u_t + \nabla \cdot (u^2 \nabla \Delta u) = 0$, in $ (0,T)\times B_R,$ with boundary conditions $u =\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu} \Delta  u  = 0$, in $(0,T)\times B_R,$ and initial data $u(0,\cdot) = g,$ in $ B_R$, where for instance

```
g[x] = 1
```

in $B_r$ and $0$ outside $B_r$, with $r < R$. 
A reference on numerical analysis for this problem is  https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/134511.

Is it possible to use Mathematica (for example `NDSolve`) to obtain and plot solutions to such equation?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into `NDSolve` and friends?

Comment: @MarcoB I don't know how to implement the boundary conditions on `NDSolve` or if using `NDSolve` is actually the correct approach.

Comment: That's a nonlinear PDE and Mathematica's FEM capacities don't support that at the moment (version 11.3). Moreover, it is a fourth order PDE and I doubt that these are supported at all.You _could_ try reformulate this as a coupled system of order 2 and use `NDSolve` for solving linearized PDEs in order to implement a semi-implicit time integrator...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher We can rewrite the PDE as $u_t + \nabla \cdot (u^2 \nabla w) = 0$ and $w = \Delta u$, but I don't know how to approach systems with Mathematica.

Comment: for fourth order PDE problems, We can use Isogeometric Analysis to solve it, but I am not sure, does Mathematica support Isogeometric Analysis?

Comment: Please write your PDE, boundary conditions, and initial conditions in Mathematica format.